# Dynamic Jasper issue for HTML content when export to pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation, dynamic-jasper

I am using DynamicJasper to create jasper reports in runtime. In my report there is a String column with values coming in html format.
I am trying to display them as HTML, it is working when the report is exported in to various formats like HTML. And while previewing in JasperReport viewer with the generated Jasper print it is working fine.

The problem is when the report is exported to pdf , the html formatting is gone for Bold and Italics. Tags like `<U>, <SUB>, <LI>` are working. The issue is noticed for `<B> and <I>.`Any idea what to do?. Can paste the code if required. No error or warning in the console

Comment: Do you have a template (*jrxml*)?

Comment: Post your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve